# Run code when an element is added to a list

Tags: python, list

How do I detect when something is added to a list? Is there an equivalent to the dictionary `__setitem__` method, that will get called when something is added to the list by `insert`, `extend`, `append` or using `+` or `+=` (`__add__`, `__iadd__`), or some other method that I probably forgot about? Or do I need to hook into each of those methods, one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to override each method separately. Especially as the operations you've mentioned are different in nature - `append`, `insert`, `extend`, and `+=` modify the list in place while `+` creates a new list.

If you're feeling fancy, this is a potential way to do it without having to write too much boilerplate:

```
class MyList(list):
    pass

for method in ['append', 'insert', 'extend', '__add__', '__iadd__']:
    def code_added(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your code here
        getattr(super(MyList, self), method)(*args, **kwargs)

    setattr(MyList, method, code_added)
```

Depending on what the code you want to run accesses, you might need to handle `__add__` separately.

Comment: `+=` doesn't create a new list.

Comment: @khelwood It actually does! It then assigns it to the variable, but it's not the same object.

Comment: I can see how you would think it does, but it doesn't. Try it.

Comment: @obskyr you're mixing this up with `+=` for strings or other immutable objects. Lists are mutable, hence this is the same as `.extend` (apart from that, your answer is the best ATM :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Huh, you're right! It doesn't call `extend`, but it does modify the list in place.

Answer (score 4):

as obskyr answer is suggesting, you have to define a child class of `list` and override a lot of methods, and test carefully to see if you're not missing something.

My approach uses a deeper hook using `__getattribute__` (for method calls), `__iadd__` (for `+=`) and `__setitem__` (for slice assignment) to catch the maximum of changes, and call the original parent method so it acts like a generic middleman:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getattribute__(self,a):
        if a in {"append","extend","remove","insert","pop","reverse","sort","clear"}:
            print("modification by {}".format(a))
        else:
            print("not modified {}".format(a))
        return list.__getattribute__(self,a)

    def __iadd__(self,v):
        print("in place add")
        return list.__iadd__(self,v)

    def __setitem__(self,i,v):
        print("setitem {},{}".format(i,v))
        return list.__setitem__(self,i,v)

l = MyList()

l.append(12)
l.extend([12])
l.remove(12)
print(l)
l[:] = [4,5,6]
l += [5]
print(l)
```

output:

```
modification by append
modification by extend
modification by remove
[12]
setitem slice(None, None, None),[4, 5, 6]
in place add
[4, 5, 6, 5]
```

as you see

1. the list is modified properly
2. all changes are detected

I may have missed some accesses, but that seems pretty close to me.

Comment: Can't help but noticed you changed your membership test from a set to a list - any reason not to use a set?

Comment: no, it's just that I had improved the set thing in the edit box, but pasted back my old code with the += improvement.

Comment: While overkill for my needs, I like how this is both clever and readable.

Comment: your needs are important, but providing a thourough answer for your question is also important (for future readers which may be more demanding)